# PL/SQL procedure that will go through inventory one by one looking for item and updates accordingly

Tags: oracle, loops, stored-procedures, plsql

I have an **inventory** table like below:

```
warehouse_no|item_no|item_quantity
------------|-------|-------------
 1          | 1000  |          300
------------|-------|-------------
 2          | 1000  |          500
------------|-------|-------------
 3          | 1000  |          200
------------|-------|-------------
 1          | 2000  |          100
------------|-------|-------------
 2          | 2000  |          200
------------|-------|-------------
 3          | 2000  |            0
------------|-------|-------------
 1          | 3000  |          100
------------|-------|-------------
 2          | 3000  |          200
------------|-------|-------------
 3          | 3000  |            0
------------|-------|-------------
```

Now if someone for example orders 400 units item no. 1000, the pl/sql should go through the table, take 300 from warehouse 1 and 100 from warehouse 2 and update it. The resulting table should look like below:

```
warehouse_no|item_no|item_quantity
------------|-------|-------------
 1          | 1000  |            0
------------|-------|-------------
 2          | 1000  |          400
------------|-------|-------------
 3          | 1000  |          200
------------|-------|-------------
```

The procedure I wrote is below

```
PROCEDURE upd_inventory(p_item_no inventory.item_no%TYPE, p_quantity number) 
AS
 CURSOR inventory_cur IS
  select MAX(item_quantity)as quantity
  from   inventory
  where  item_no=p_item_no;

  v_order_quantity number:=p_quantity;

BEGIN
 FOR  v_inventory_cur IN inventory_cur LOOP
  UPDATE INVENTORY
  SET item_quantity = ((v_inventory_cur.quantity) - p_quantity );
  COMMIT;
 END LOOP;
END upd_inventory;
```

But as you would have noticed this will update the whole quantity column and does not solve the issue of checking through row by row taking item and updating accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: This can be solved in plain SQL, which will be much faster. Is writing a PL/SQL procedure part of the problem requirement? (That is: are you taking a class on PL/SQL procedures, and this is just a class assignment?) If not, it would be best to just state the problem, and not request a specific (and sub-optimal) way of SOLVING it.

Comment: this procedure needs to be inside my pl/sql package which takes new orders and updates all tables

Comment: @mathguy Can you please post an answer with only SQL only just for my understanding & future reference .

Comment: @pOrinG I've written an answer with one SQL statement, please, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do with one SQL query. The following query shows, how to calculate quantity to take from each warehouse, and returns a list of warehouses where we take in total 400 units of item no. 1000:

```
select warehouse_no, item_no, item_quantity,
       case when running_sum < 400 then item_quantity
            else 400 - (running_sum - item_quantity) end how_much_to_take
  from (select warehouse_no, item_no, item_quantity, 
               sum(item_quantity) over (partition by item_no 
                                        order by warehouse_no) running_sum
          from inventory
         where item_no = 1000)
 where running_sum - item_quantity < 400
```

Column `how_much_to_take` contains quantity, how much items we need to take from the warehouse.

So we can write the following `MERGE` statement:

```
merge into inventory i
using ( select warehouse_no, item_no, item_quantity, running_sum,
               case when running_sum < 400 then item_quantity
                    else 400 - (running_sum - item_quantity) end to_take
          from (select warehouse_no, item_no, item_quantity, 
                       sum(item_quantity) over (partition by item_no 
                                                order by warehouse_no) running_sum
                  from inventory
                 where item_no = 1000)
         where running_sum - item_quantity < 400
        ) how_much
   on (i.warehouse_no = how_much.awrehouse_no and i.item_no = how_much.item_no)
 when matched then update
  set i.item_quntity = i.item_quntity - how_much.to_take
```

This statement will update your table as you need. And, if you still need a procedure:

```
PROCEDURE upd_inventory(p_item_no inventory.item_no%TYPE, p_quantity number) AS
BEGIN
    merge into inventory i
    using ( select warehouse_no, item_no, item_quantity, running_sum,
                   case when running_sum < p_quantity then item_quantity
                        else p_quantity - (running_sum - item_quantity) end to_take
              from (select warehouse_no, item_no, item_quantity, 
                           sum(item_quantity) over (partition by item_no 
                                                    order by warehouse_no) running_sum
                      from inventory
                     where item_no = p_item_no)
             where running_sum - item_quantity < p_quantity
            ) how_much
       on (i.warehouse_no = how_much.awrehouse_no and i.item_no = how_much.item_no)
     when matched then update
      set i.item_quntity = i.item_quntity - how_much.to_take;
END upd_inventory;
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the logic !! :)

Comment: Thanks a  lot! Got a much better understanding now.Much appreciated

Comment: @Dmitry However it doesn't account for if the total quantity is not enough. We can add another where condition to check that & if the records count updated = 0 then the job was unsuccessful because of insufficient quantity. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @pOrinG Yes, I forgot about this case. I think it is better to check total quantity as `select sum(item_quantity) from inventory where item_no = 1000`. If the total quantity is less then required, then just simply update and set 0 everywhere, and return a missing amount.

Answer (score 0):

Use item_no and warehouse_no as where condition to update item_quantity   in inventory table. In which you need to find a pattern to use warehouse_no in where  condition.

Answer (score 0):

Below function will work for your requirement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
DEDUCT_INV (in_item_no In Number,in_quantity  In Number) 
Is

TYPE someRefCursor IS REF CURSOR;
fetchWareHouseQuantitiesCursor someRefCursor;

tempWareHouseNo temp_inventory.warehouse_no%type;
tempItemQuantity temp_inventory.item_quantity%type;
requiredQuantity temp_inventory.item_quantity%type := in_quantity;

Begin

    Open fetchWareHouseQuantitiesCursor For 
    Select warehouse_no, item_quantity 
    From temp_inventory 
    Where item_no = in_item_no And item_quantity != 0
    order by warehouse_no;

    /* Ignoring 0 quantity warehouses 
    & also ordering by warehouse 
    but if required can be ordered by item_quantity desc so
    minimum warehouses are touched which is more efficient*/

    LOOP
        Fetch fetchWareHouseQuantitiesCursor Into tempWareHouseNo,tempItemQuantity;

        Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Required:'||requiredQuantity||'.');

        Exit When fetchWareHouseQuantitiesCursor%NotFound;

        Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Fetched:'||tempWareHouseNo||','||tempItemQuantity||'.');

        if(requiredQuantity > tempItemQuantity)
        then

            Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Updating:'||tempWareHouseNo||','||tempItemQuantity||' by 0.');

            update temp_inventory set item_quantity = 0 where warehouse_no = tempWareHouseNo And item_no = in_item_no;

            requiredQuantity:= requiredQuantity - tempItemQuantity;

        else

            Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Updating:'||tempWareHouseNo||','||tempItemQuantity||' by '||(tempItemQuantity - requiredQuantity)||'.');

            update temp_inventory set item_quantity = item_quantity-requiredQuantity where warehouse_no = tempWareHouseNo And item_no = in_item_no;

            requiredQuantity:= 0;

            exit;

        end if;

    END LOOP;

    Close fetchWareHouseQuantitiesCursor;

    if(requiredQuantity != 0)
    then
        rollback;

        Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Job Failed. Insufficient storage. Missing:'||requiredQuantity||' quantity.');
    else
        commit;

        Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Job Completed Successfully.');
    end if;

    return;

End;
/

execute DEDUCT_INV(1000,400);
```

Comment: You are a legend. That worked! Thanks for taking time to write that long code much appreciated.

Comment: @dwalker Aah, hope you understand the logic. Dmitry with the single statement has written something which is much more interesting.

Comment: @dwalker I also forgot to close cursor before. Please take that into account if you are using the code.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered this already, but just for fun I'll share the version I started anyway:

```
procedure upd_inventory
    ( p_item_no   inventory.item_no%type
    , p_quantity  inventory.item_quantity%type )
is
    l_total_stocked inventory.item_quantity%type := 0;
    l_outstanding inventory.item_quantity%type := p_quantity;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Item ' || p_item_no || ' target: ' || p_quantity);

    for r in (
        select i.item_no, i.warehouse_no
             , i.item_quantity as warehouse_quantity
             , i.item_quantity as warehouse_remaining
             , sum(i.item_quantity) over () as total_quantity
        from   inventory i
        where  i.item_no = p_item_no
        and    i.item_quantity > 0
        for update
        order by i.item_quantity desc
    )
    loop
        l_total_stocked := r.total_quantity;  -- redundant after first iteration but avoids separate query

        update inventory i
        set    i.item_quantity = greatest(r.warehouse_quantity - l_outstanding, 0)
        where  i.warehouse_no = r.warehouse_no
        and    i.item_no = p_item_no
        returning i.item_quantity into r.warehouse_remaining;

        dbms_output.put_line('Warehouse '||r.warehouse_no || ': reducing stock by ' || (r.warehouse_quantity - r.warehouse_remaining));

        l_outstanding := l_outstanding - (r.warehouse_quantity - r.warehouse_remaining);

        exit when l_outstanding = 0;
    end loop;

    if l_outstanding = 0 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Item ' || p_item_no || ' stock reduced by ' || p_quantity);
    else
        raise_application_error
        ( -20000
        , 'Insufficient stock for item ' || p_item_no ||
          ': stocked: ' || l_total_stocked || ', requested: ' || p_quantity ||
          ', short: ' || (p_quantity - l_total_stocked) );
    end if;

end upd_inventory;
```

While the single `merge` approach is doubtless fastest (and avoids the locking needed to prevent lost updates in a multi-user environment), I would personally be concerned about support and maintenance. Maybe I could rewrite my cursor using a `model` clause or a recursive `with`, but the poor developer given the task of updating it one day to take into account delivery distance or something will have a much harder job.

I have not committed or rolled back within the procedure because generally it is best to leave this to the caller, but if you want to you can commit at the end (not in the middle!) Note that raising an exception implicitly rolls back the updates. If you need to roll back explicitly then declare a savepoint at the start and roll back to that.

Probably a real procedure would use a standard logger for the diagnostic messages rather than `dbms_output`.

Comment: nice one.very clear and logical. Thank you for taking time to write it.